# Sort ABMultiValueRef(kABPersonPhoneProperty)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, abaddressbook, abmultivalue

Well, to get phones property with `ABAddressBook`, I use a loop.

**EDIT : code I've tried :**

```
    ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

                        for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++) {

            NSMutableString *phone = [CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j)) mutableCopy];
if ([phone hasPrefix:@"06"] || [phone hasPrefix:@"07"]){
    person.number = phone;
    }
```

But I don't think this is the best option..?

Maybe something like :

```
if (ABMultiValueRef hasprefix...06 ||  07){
person.number = phones
}
```

When the contact has multiple value of phone numbers, I can count it with `ABMultiValueGetCount(phones)`.

Well, now take an example :

The contact « Peter » has got 5 phone numbers in `ABAddressBook` (`NSLog` phones):

02 35 00 00 00

07 00 00 00 00

+1(919)949-8234

06 00 00 00 00

9009498923

I would like to sort these numbers, and store only ONE in `NSString` :

if number begins by 07 —> TAKE IT. (assign to `NSString`)

if number begins by 06 —> TAKE IT. (assign to `NSString`)

if other number —> Don’t assign.

if they are two phone number : one with 06, one with 07, take the last registered in `ABAddressBook` (or if this not possible/too complicated, take the number beginning by 07).

I would like to make this loop for every contact in `ABAddressBook`. and every contact has only ONE number (or 0 if numbers don't begin by 06 or 07).

In my example :

Peter has got this number : 07 00 00 00 00

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: @rmaddy updated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Best answer I've found myself :

```
ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                            for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++) 
{   
if ([CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j)) hasPrefix:@"07"] 
|| [CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j)) hasPrefix:@"06"] 
||[CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j)) hasPrefix:@"+33"])
        {

}
}
```